# Adding icon to a search dropdown of semanticui

Tags: ruby-on-rails, semantic-ui

I would like to add a semantic ui icon to a search dropdown that should be present regardless of the selected option on a ruby on rails application. Basically, it should look something like this:

[image]

What I have so far is a working search dropdown with the following code:

```
= select_tag(:"q[camera_id_eq]", content_tag(:option, "Choose location . . .", value: "") + options_from_collection_for_select(Camera.all, "id", "full_location"), class: 'ui fluid search selection dropdown')
```

I checked the [semantic ui dropdown documentation](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html) and I didn't find a solution for this particular problem. They only have one for the button implementation of a dropdown but the same approach didn't work in my case.

Comment: You need to create a custom one.
maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42432040/semantic-ui-dropdown-display-image-as-icon

Comment: Thanks for this. However, the example from that assigns unique icons per option in the dropdown. What I wanted to achieve is attaching a permanent icon to the dropdown search field itself so the same icon should be there regardless of the option you pick. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am practically new to Frontend, but I hope and this helps you. I share you the following examples. Assuming you are inside in Form, As far as I know, everything is in the HTML structure, using `<div>` and `<i>` for the `text_field`, but for `collection_select` I made it in a different way, I did not achieve it in an easier way.

If you use a text_field and a collection_select.

```
<%= form_with(model: person, local: true, html: { class: "ui form", autocomplete: "off" }) do |form| %>
     <div class="field">
         <%= form.label :name %>
         <div class="ui right icon input">
            <%= form.text_field :name %>
            <i class="user icon"></i>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <%= form.label :country_id %>
            <%= form.collection_select :country_id, @countries,:id, :name, options = {:prompt => 'Select a Country...'}, html_options = {class: "ui fluid search selection dropdown"}%>
        </div>
                
    <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
    </div>
 <% end %>
```

And I put my Js `$('.dropdown').dropdown();` on my application.js

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function()
 {
  // Person form dropdown
  $('.dropdown').dropdown();    
})
```

Other way for do that:

Skip the html_options on your view.

```
<div class="field">
    <%= form.label :country_id %>
    <%= form.collection_select :country_id, @countries,:id, :name, options = {:prompt => 'Select a Country...'} %>
</div>
```

And in your application.js add the html_options with the next code and the function dropdown(), by the way Just consider having the ID of your element, in my case it is `#person_country_id`:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function()
     {
    $('#person_country_id').addClass("ui fluid search selection dropdown")
       .dropdown();
})
```

Regards.